# Set Cron in Azure that runs from a particular time every 5 minutes

Tags: azure, cron, timer-trigger

Is it possible to run a timer trigger function 5 mins starting from a particular time and date.

I want the timer trigger function to run from for eg 7 Aug 2023 from 12:00 am at every five mins.

Eg 0 0 0,23 7 Aug

This run 7 Aug only. But I want the Cron to start running from 7 Aug 2023 every 5 mins from 12:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below CRON expression, which will trigger from 7th-31st August every day for every 5 minutes starting at 12:00AM

```
  0 */5 * 7-31 8 * OR  0 */5 0-23 7-31 8 *
```

Also, you can make use this [NCRON expression generator](https://ncrontab.swimburger.net/) to review/evaluate your CRON expression.

For more information, refer to this [NCRONTAB expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#ncrontab-expressions) on how to built a CORN expression from function app.

Comment: The keyword is **CRON**, not **CORN**